# Split button dropdowns issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and when I create a button with dropdown he incorrectly places the arrow.

The following is a sample image.

http://postimg.org/image/5ccnnfwsl/

I'm using the code

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good to me [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3hu51gg3/). Did you change the display property of any of bootstraps build in classes?

Comment: Looks like you are using `display: flex` on one of those classes `.btn-group .btn` .

Comment: Hello David,
I did not change any of the bootstrap file, I am using the "sb-admin-2" and custom css there not these classes, so I do not know where might be the problem, I have also updated the bootstrap root file other and the error remains.

Comment: Hello, thank you to all answer, but the problem is that I had not set the <! DOCTYPE html>, does anyone know why without this tag it just broke that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had not set the `<! DOCTYPE html>`. Does anyone know why without this tag it just broke that element?

Comment: Hello, thank you to all answer, but the problem is that I had not set the <! DOCTYPE html>, does anyone know why without this tag it just broke that element?

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this could be the `line-height` property for your `dropdown-toggle` class being set to 0.